# What is V65/III in D major?

Tags: theory, harmony, analysis, roman-numerals

In the key of D major what is V65/III but, the III is natural? I'm having a hard time with this. Also, V7/bVI?

Answer (score 3):

In D major, III is an F♯ major chord. (It isn't diatonic: iii or F♯ minor is.) That being the case, V<sup>6</sup><sub>5</sub>/III is a first inversion dominant seventh chord on C♯ (see Ex. 1). However, V<sup>6</sup><sub>5</sub>/III is the same chord as V<sup>6</sup><sub>5</sub>/iii, so it isn't that far removed from the key as secondary sevenths go.

♭VI in D major is going to be a B♭ major chord. It's pretty much a borrowing from the parallel minor key (D minor). That being the case, then V<sup>7</sup>/♭VI is going to be a dominant seventh on F (see Ex. 2).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually going to have to disagree with the first half of Patrx2's answer. The second half is totally fine; ♭VI in D major is B♭, so the V<sup>7</sup>/♭VI will in fact be `F A C E♭`.

As for the first one, OP asked:

> In the key of D major what is V65/III but, the III is natural?

Since the III is both uppercase (thus not iii, which would be F♯ minor) *and* natural, it seems the question is asking for the V<sup>6</sup><sub>5</sub>/F (F being the "naturalled" [that is, lowered] third scale degree). The V<sup>7</sup> of F is a C<sup>7</sup> chord, `C E G B♭`, which will have the `E` in the bass for its <sup>6</sup><sub>5</sub> position.

Comment: Then it becomes V7/♭III, no?

Comment: fIII or nIII, both work.

Comment: Ah. Don't think I've ever seen the natural used, probably because it isn't very "key-agnostic".

Comment: But in the case of D Major, nIII would be more correct than fIII.

Comment: That's my point, Richard. This notation is _meant_ to be key-agnostic: III or iii for the mediant degree in major, ♭III or ♭iii for the minor's mediant, _regardless_ of where the tonic is situated.

Comment: Should the question then be about V65/bIII. As III will always be F# in D maj. If the III in question needs to be F natural, it's got to be called bIII, surely? which then equates to a flattened sharp note, e.g. natural.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer; given that the second half of the question is about bVI it makes sense that both questions are dealing with standard modal mixture chords. I agree with @user16935 that key-agnostic bIII is a slightly superior way to write it, but using a natural is very common. However, I think it would help the OP if the answers made it clear that bIII and bVI are common modal mixture chords, since that’s the common link between the two halves of the question.

Comment: Yes, if we're using the I, II, III... system of naming chords, bIII is the usual way, whether the actual root is a flat, sharp or natural.   (It COULD be a sharp, in D# major...)

Answer (score 0):

In D major III is an F#major chord.  But you say it's a natural, so I think we're talking about F major (which would normally be labelled as bIII).  So you're asking for the first inversion dominant 7th of F, which is C7/E  (C7 with E as the lowest note).

bVI in D is Bb.   The dominant of Bb is F.

The third note of the D major scale is F#.  The minor third is F natural.  But we call the F chord bIII, even though 'flattening' it resulted in a natural.

In the same way, consider F major.  Fourth note is Bb.  So a Bb chord is IV. We call a B (natural) chord #IV, even though the actual note is a natural.  The Bb has been 'sharpened' to Bnat.